# Método incorreto em formulário gerado pelo CakePHP 2.4

Tags: php, cakephp

Meu problema ocorre com o seguinte código:

```php
<?php
echo $this->Form->create(
  'Page',
  array(
    'url' => array(
      'controller' => 'pages',
      'action' => 'delete',
      $this->request->data['Page']['id'],
      'admin' => true
    ),
    'id' => 'PageDeleteForm',
    'method' => 'POST',
    'class' => 'hide'
  )
);

echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

O resultado disso, é o seguinte:

```html
<form action="/admin/pages/delete/16" id="PageDeleteForm" method="post" class="hide" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <div style="display:none;">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
  </div>
</form>
```

Com isso, o CakePHP retorna pra mim: **Method not allowed**, pois minha `action` permite apenas `POST` ou `DELETE`.

Por qual motivo o campo `_method` está sendo gerado com o valor **PUT**?

Comment: Experimente passar `'type'=> 'POST'` em vez de method.

Comment: @bfavaretto Problema resolvido! A questão é: porque ele setou o method como POST, e o input como PUT? Mas enfim, o problema inicial foi resolvido. Obrigado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu não tenho certeza, mas acredito que o CakePHP se confundiu quando você passou `'method'=>  'POST'` como opção.

O parâmetro padrão, segundo a [documentação](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-FormHelper.html#_create), é `type`, e não `method` (que é o nome do atributo gerado).

> `type` Form method defaults to POST

Comment: Sim, de qualquer forma, eu não acho que foi confusão. Porém vou checar isso assim que possível.